# PHP system chancing case of urlencode

Tags: php

I am sending a urlencoded string to a system which they are then sending back to me, but the URL encoded characters have a lowercase instead of uppercase character in them.

Is there an easy way for me to find each instance and change it to uppercase?

Here's an example

What I am sending:

```
6Vc6K83k%2FnBWb6sOfc0fcQiMOttpKJci9o%2B%2BdMBs0MCGJgQkgyr6zV%2FO8hqRATKW1uUYEs5zOqKso36x%2BydCc6
```

What I get in return:

```
6Vc6K83k%2fnBWb6sOfc0fcQiMOttpKJci9o%2b%2bdMBs0MCGJgQkgyr6zV%2fO8hqRATKW1uUYEs5zOqKso36x%2bydCc6
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why does it need to be changed?  It sounds like you're trying to solve a symptom of a different problem entirely.

Comment: Because that information is a semi-encrypted hash and it's messing up the decryption method on the receiving end.

Comment: Maybe url-decode it and then url-encode it again?  If the decoding step succeeds in producing the original string, then re-encoding it should result in the same value you originally sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback` and replace `/%[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/` with its uppercase equivalent using `strtoupper`:

5.3+:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('/%[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/', function($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[0]);
}, $string);
```

Less than 5.3:

```
function preg_replace_callback_uppercaser($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[0]);
}
$string = preg_replace_callback('/%[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/', 'preg_replace_callback_uppercaser', $string);
```

---

#### Demo

```
<?php
    $string = '6Vc6K83k%2fnBWb6sOfc0fcQiMOttpKJci9o%2b%2bdMBs0MCGJgQkgyr6zV%2fO8hqRATKW1uUYEs5zOqKso36x%2bydCc6';

    $string = preg_replace_callback('/%[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/', function($match) {
        return strtoupper($match[0]);
    }, $string);

    var_dump($string);
?>
```

Outputs:

> string(96) "6Vc6K83k%2FnBWb6sOfc0fcQiMOttpKJci9o%2B%2BdMBs0MCGJgQkgyr6zV%2FO8hqRATKW1uUYEs5zOqKso36x%2BydCc6"

[**Link to live demo**](https://eval.in/57384)

---

Alternatively, [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david)'s `$string = urlencode(urldecode($string));` works fine.